# Digit only text field in JSF

Tags: jsf

How to allow a text field to permit only digits in JSF? I searched about it on Google a lot but could not find the solution in JSF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just bind it to an `Integer` property.

E.g.

```
private Integer number;
```

with

```
<h:inputText id="number" value="#{bean.number}" />
<h:message for="number" />
```

It'll show a conversion error when you submit non-digits.

Comment: @BalusC The problem comes if you want a bigger number thant one that fits in an Integer (or Long). What if you want to a string to have only numbers (and keep the zeroes in the left)?

Comment: @eljunior: if the number is bigger than `Long`, then use `BigDecimal`. But if you want to pad it with zeroes, you need a custom `Converter` or just make it a `String` and supply a custom `Validator`.