# how can i set <p:inputText> field to accept Numbers and special characters in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working with Java Server Faces and Primefaces. One of my requirement is, do not allow only numbers in input text field(that means allow characters and special symbols).
I can only allow the number by

```
<p:inputText value="#{doctorindBean.age}" id="age" tabindex="2" maxlength="30">
    <pe:keyFilter mask="num"></pe:keyFilter>
</p:inputText>
```

Only characters by

```
<p:inputText value="#{doctorindBean.doclastname}" id="lastname" tabindex="2" maxlength="30">
        <pe:keyFilter mask="alpha"></pe:keyFilter>
    </p:inputText>
```

When I use 2nd one(i.e characters only), I can't use special characters.

But my scenario is to allow characters and special symbols. How can I do this?
Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try with a nice trick by [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc)

- bind it to an Integer property.

  ```
    <h:inputText id="number" value="#{bean.number}" />
    <h:message for="number" />
  ```

  In Bean Class

  `private Integer number;`

  The form will not get submit, It'll show a conversion error when you submit non-digits.     Codes Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7897126/1923055)
- If you Want Certain Prediction in Input Elements means go with [`<p:inputMask />`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inputMask.jsf)

**Updated**

- If you want to allow special character in text field , store the text as String and 
  *Parse Some validation in Bean class*

You can try the following scenario

```
 public String setNumber(String number)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<mobile.length();i++)
    {
        if((int)number.charAt(i)>65 && (int)number.charAt(i)<90 || (int)number.charAt(i)>97 && (int)number.charAt(i)<122)
        {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Exception"); //Throwing manual exception
        }
    }
      this.number=number;
    }
```

**It allows only Integer and Special Charactor**....

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, my scenario is to allow characters and  special letters. Can you suggest me how can i do???

Comment: @user2314868 Refer Updated ans